# Check if field exists, delete it and create a new one

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a NodeJS program that on a given document, it checks if a field exists from a given list of fields - lets say the key we are looking for is `key1`. If the field exists it is deleted and a new field is added with the field incremented - `key2` with some value.

```
// Get the `FieldValue` object
let FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;

// Create a document reference
let cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

// Remove the 'capital' field from the document
let removeCapital = cityRef.update({
  capital: FieldValue.delete()
});
```

From the documentation I found the way to delete a field but I am not sure how to check if the key exists so the program knows what key to create after the deletion.

For the program the key might be any sequence of letters followed by a sequence of numbers - `key1`, `key2`, `key3` etc, so I need a way to know which of those exists in order to correctly delete and then increment the new one

Comment: If all the changes to the document must happen at the same time, consider using a transaction to read, modify, and write the document in one operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know the list of fields for a document you need to fetch it with the `get()` method, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get

For example:

```
let cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

cityRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

In the code above, `doc` is a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html) and if you call the [`data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html#data) method it will return "all fields in the document as an Object."

You just have to loop over the Object returned by the `data()` method to get the value `X` of the `key(X)` field, then increment it and write a new field `key(X+1)` with, for example, the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) method.

---

**Note that, depending on your exact requirement, you may have to use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).**